# When a linear system is contained in another in a K3 surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a K3 surface. Let $D$ be a divisor on $X$. Then we have the exact sequence $0\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_X(-D)\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_X\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_D\longrightarrow 0$. If $L$ is a line bundle on $X$, such that $L$ and $L-D$ have sections, then tensoring the above sequence by $L$ we get that $H^0(L-D)\subset H^0(L)$. But this means that $|L-D|\subset |L|$ right? But if $C\in |L-D|\subset |L|$, then the genus $g$ of $C$ satisfies by adjunction formula that $2g-2$ is $(L-D)^2$, it is also $L^2$ right? What is the issue here? I am not able to understand.

Comment: The inclusion $|L-D|\subset |L|$ is, $C\mapsto C+D$, so genus of $C$ is $(L-D)^2/2 +1$ and genus of $(C+D)^2$ is $L^2/2+1$. What adjunction formula are you using?

Comment: Sorry, in the above, $(C+D)^2$ should be $C+D$.

Comment: Thanks @mohan! I made an error, I wanted to say $2g-2$, I have corrected it. Ah! $C\mapsto C+D$, I naively assumed that $C$ itself will be an element of $|L|$. But this also means that $Pic(C)\longrightarrow Pic (C+D)$ right?

Comment: I do not understand your statement about Pic.

Comment: Sorry I meant to ask if there is any relation between $Pic^d(C)$ and $Pic^d(C+D)$?. Essentially the curves are identified in the linear systems right, so I had this question. @Mohan

Comment: There is no natural map $Pic C\to Pic C+D$. You have restriction map going the other way in general.